# VS2017 Break build using tslint on .js files

Tags: visual-studio-2017, eslint, tslint

I found the Typescript Analyzer extension via [Set up TSLint for VS2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42824723/set-up-tslint-for-vs2017)

However it only works on .ts files. I want to be able to run tslint on .js files and have it break the build on errors. I wasn't able to get my builds to break using eslint either.

Running tslint via command line works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TypeScript Analyzer extension does now support linting JavaScript files, including breaking the build on errors.  There's a 'Lint .js and .jsx files' option on Tools/Options/TypeScript Analyzer.

For this to work you need to enable the option in Tools/Options and to create a 'jsRules' section in your tslint.json at the same level as the existing 'rules' section (Tools/TypeScript Analyzer/Edit TSLint settings). Rules that apply to .ts and .tsx files then appear in the existing 'rules' section, and rules that apply to .js and .jsx files need to be added to the new 'jsRules' section.

This means if you want a rule to apply to .ts and .js files it needs to appear twice in tslint.json, once in each section. Some rules will only work with TypeScript (.ts and .tsx) files. See the [TSLint documentation](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/) for more details.

For example, a tslint.json that (only) applies the no-console rule to both TypeScript and JavaScript files would look as below:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "no-console": true
  },
   "jsRules": {
    "no-console": true
  }
}
```

To break the build on errors as usual set 'Show errors' and 'Run on build' to True in Tools/Options/TypeScript Analyzer.